# POTUS’ transformative American Jobs Plan

Tags: pronunciation, reading-aloud

Is POTUS pronounced letter by letter: P,O,T,U,S? Or is it pronounced as /ˈpəʊ.təs/?

> Nancy Pelosi tweeted:
> Building Back Better means investing in the American people, building up our infrastructure and creating good-paying jobs for the future. @**POTUS’ transformative American Jobs Plan** is a blueprint for a better future.
> Source: [Twitter](https://twitter.com/SpeakerPelosi/status/1390696197451665411)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pronounced as a word ([Forvo](https://forvo.com/word/potus/), [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/POTUS)). "P O T U S" is quite the mouthful.

Comment: Since it's a reference to the President's twitter handle, it would also be acceptable to substitute "the President" when saying it out loud.